# python setup.py bdist_wheel does not create build/ directories

Tags: python

I was trying to create a wheel for a python project. Here is the info:

```
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_py
installing to build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel
running install
running install_lib
creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel
creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel/py2asy
copying build/lib/py2asy/config.py -> build/bdist.linux-   x86_64/wheel/py2asy
copying build/lib/py2asy/base.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel/py2asy
copying build/lib/py2asy/matrix.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel/py2asy
copying build/lib/py2asy/__init__.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel/py2asy
copying build/lib/py2asy/figures.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel/py2asy
running install_egg_info
running egg_info
writing top-level names to py2asy.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to py2asy.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing py2asy.egg-info/PKG-INFO
reading manifest file 'py2asy.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
writing manifest file 'py2asy.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
Copying py2asy.egg-info to build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel/py2asy-0.1.2-py3.4.egg-info
running install_scripts
creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel/py2asy-0.1.2.dist-info/WHEEL
```

The problem is that the directory build/bdist.linux-x86_64 is empty.

Comment: Why is that a problem?  The important part is that the wheel is created in `dist/`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is the first time I used wheel.